# Node.js one session per user

Tags: node.js, passport.js

How can I prevent my users to be logged in my system from two devices same time? So if user logged in from computer, when he logins from different computer, session on first automatically closes (don't need make it realtime).

I use node.js, express.js, mongoose, passport, connect-mongo (to store sessions in database).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can generate a token when user logs in and save it in your database against that user. Now with each request you will need to send this token to server. Consider the following scenario:

User A logs in from Computer A and a token 123 is generated and saved in database. Now whenever User A sends a request to server, it first checks for a valid session and then loads user's token from database to check if its valid.

Now User A logs into the website from Computer B and a token 456 is assigned to the user and is overwritten in database. Next time when User A sends a request from Computer A, server checks for a valid session and when it gets the token from database there is a mismatch indicating that user has logged in from somewhere else so current session is invalid.