# Passport middleware, check if the user already has a living session from

Tags: express, passport.js, angular-fullstack

I am building a web application using [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack). The stack is using [express-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sessions) for session storage (in Mongodb) and passport.js for authentication.

I want to limit each user to a single login session. I am trying find a way to check if a user already has a living session when they login.

Is there a way to programmatically call a route to query mongodb from the passport middleware?

```
'use strict';

import path from 'path';

import passport from 'passport';
import {Strategy as LocalStrategy} from 'passport-local';

import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';

import _ from 'lodash';
import Session from '../../api/session/session.model';

var app = express();
require('run-middleware')(app);

function localAuthenticate(User, email, password, done, req) {
  User.findOne({
    email: email.toLowerCase()
  }).exec()
    .then(user => {

      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'This email is not registered.'
        });
      }

      // HERE is where I am trying to check if a user
      // already has a living session when they login

      // I tried to use the runMiddleware
      // to query mongodb for all the existing sessions
      // but I get this error: http://pastebin.com/YTeu5AwA
      app.runMiddleware('/sessions',{},function(code,data){
        console.log(code) // 200 
        console.log(data) // { user: '20', name: 'Moyshale' }
      });

      // Is there a way to access and use an existing route?

      user.authenticate(password, function(authError, authenticated) {
        if (authError) {
          return done(authError);
        }
        if (!authenticated) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'This password is not correct.' });
        } else {
          return done(null, user);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => done(err));
}

export function setup(User, config) {

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true,
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password' // this is the virtual field on the model
  }, function(req, email, password, done) {
    return localAuthenticate(User, email, password, done, req);
  }));
}
```

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434922/node-js-one-session-per-user), and its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out and I'll try and explain what I did. My specific implementation required me to set up user 'seats', where each user is part of a group and each group is limited in N number of logins at a single time.

[image]

As I mentioned in the question, I am using the angular fullstack yeoman generator, so this solution is specific to that setup.

1. I created a 'sessions' [API endpoint](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/docs/generators/endpoint.md) so that I could query and modify the sessions stored in the mongo db. I included a 'seat' record with type Number into the sessions model. This is used to keep track of the users seat status for each session. Each user is given a 'loginSeat' value which is used to populate this filed. Also the session now has a seatAllowed of type Boolean, true: the user is allowed to access the site, false: the user is not allowed access to the site.

   ```
   'use strict';

   import mongoose from 'mongoose';

   var SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     _id: String,
     session: String,
     expires: Date,
     seat: Number,
     seatAllowed: Boolean // true: the user is allowed to access the site, false: the user is not allowed access to the site
   });

   export default mongoose.model('Session', SessionSchema);
   ```
2. I modified `server/auth/login/passport.js` so that when a user logs into the site, all other users with a matching seat are bumped out.

   ```
   'use strict';

   import path from 'path';

   import passport from 'passport';
   import {Strategy as LocalStrategy} from 'passport-local';
   import _ from 'lodash';
   import Sessions from '../../api/session/session.model';

   function saveUpdates(updates) {
     return function(entity) {
       var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
       return updated.save()
         .then(updated => {
           return updated;
         });
     };
   }

   function localAuthenticate(User, email, password, done, req) {
     User.findOne({
       email: email.toLowerCase()
     }).exec()
       .then(user => {
         if (!user) {
           return done(null, false, {
             message: 'This email is not registered.'
           });
         }

         // When a user logs into the site we flag their seat as allowed
         var updateSession = {'seat': user.loginSeat, 'seatAllowed': true};

         Sessions.findById(req.session.id).exec()
           .then(saveUpdates(updateSession))

         // When a user logs into the site, we disallow the seats of all other sessions with matching seat
         Sessions.find().exec()
           .then(sessions => {

           // Check for existing user logged in with matching login seat
           for (var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
             if (sessions[i].seat === user.loginSeat && sessions[i].id !== req.session.id) {
               console.log('DISALOW SEAT:');
               var updateSession = {'seatAllowed': false};

               Sessions.findById(sessions[i].id).exec()
                 .then(saveUpdates(updateSession));
             }
           }
         });

         user.authenticate(password, function(authError, authenticated) {
           if (authError) {
             return done(authError);
           }
           if (!authenticated) {
             return done(null, false, { message: 'This password is not correct.' });
           } else {
             return done(null, user);
           }
         });
       })
       .catch(err => done(err));
   }

   export function setup(User, config) {

     passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
       passReqToCallback: true,
       usernameField: 'email',
       passwordField: 'password' // this is the virtual field on the model
     }, function(req, email, password, done) {
       return localAuthenticate(User, email, password, done, req);
     }));
   }
   ```
3. Each time the client makes a request the `isAuthenticated` function is triggered. This is where I check for the seaAllowed boolean for the current session, if true, allow the user to access the site, otherwise logout the user:

   ```
   function saveUpdates(updates) {
     return function(entity) {
       var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
       return updated.save()
         .then(updated => {
           return updated;
         });
     };
   }

   /**
    * Attaches the user object to the request if authenticated
    * Otherwise returns 403
    */
   export function isAuthenticated() {

     return compose()
       // Validate jwt
       .use(function(req, res, next) {

         // Allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
         if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
           req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
         }
         validateJwt(req, res, next);

       })
       // Attach user to request
       .use(function(req, res, next) {

         User.findById(req.user._id).exec()
           .then(user => {
             if (!user) {
               return res.status(401).end();
             }
             req.user = user;

             ///////////////////////////
             // Login seat limitation //
             ///////////////////////////

             // Check if the user seat is allowed
             Sessions.findById(req.session.id).exec()
               .then(thisSession => {
                 // TODO access the session in a better way
                 if (thisSession.seatAllowed === false || thisSession.seatAllowed === undefined) {
                   res.redirect('/login');
                 }
             })
             next();
           })
           .catch(err => next(err));
       });
   }
   ```

Thats it.